# How do I append to a file without adding '\n'?

Tags: python, file-io

I'm reading and appending to a text file that is being opened and read every time my Python program runs. It's basically a log of strings. 
The problem is that when I initially write to the blank file, I have to include `action.write('\n')` in order for the next string to be printed on the next line.

But then, when I read through the file the next time my Python program runs, it reads the "\n" and it gets concatenated to the previous element, which is added to a list.

Here's what is basically happening:

```
pc = ["121", "343", "565", "787"]

with open(r"C:\tt.txt", "r+") as act:
   curr=[]

   for row in act:
      if row == '\n':
         pass
      else:
         curr.append(row)

   for i in pc:
      act.write(i)
      act.write("\n")

print curr

>> curr = ['121\n', '343\n', '565\n', '787\n', '121\n', '343\n', '565\n', '787\n', '121\n', '343\n', '565\n', '787\n', '121\n', '343\n', '565\n', '787\n', '121\n', '343\n', '565\n', '787\n']
```

I'm really stumped as to how to get around this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strip the lines:

```
for row in act:
    row = row.strip()
    if row:
        curr.append(row)
```

Comment: This won't work if a row contains leading or trailing whitespaces. They will be stripped as well as newline character.

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha: True! This method will only work if that's okay (and for the lines in the question, which are just numbers, it probably is).

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha `row.rstrip('\n')` is the safest, the method still works however we usually assume that's not the case and just use plain `.strip()` anyway because it's quicker

Comment: Ahhh this is perfect. Don't know how I didn't think of this. To make sure, removing just spaces and not new line characters would be `row = row.replace(' ', '')` correct?

Comment: @iarcfsil That removes any spaces in the string

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the last character from each row

```
for row in act:
row = row[:-1]
if row:
    curr.append(row)
```